# register user to .net core from mobile

Tags: asp.net-core

i try to  register user from **xamarin** in .net core with enabled  Identity and  membership system it return true but no user registered in  database.
also i check with **MVC** web site and all things  is Ok

my code is

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var model = new RegisterBindingModel
                    {
                        Email = email,
                        Password = password,
                        ConfirmPassword = confirmPassword
                    };

                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

                    HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(json);

                    httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

                    var response = await client.PostAsync(
                        Constants.SignalrEndpointAddress + "Account/Register", httpContent);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Debug your api.

Comment: i try but visual studio dos not step in to code when i initiate request from emulator, it happens by chrome

Comment: debug problem  solved after update  vs to new version, but new problem is that model always null in controllers method  and as result , model have validation error  maybe  my HTTP request need additional config .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is in **StringContent**  and my code ended up to this:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
                {
                var model = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                    {"Email", email },
                    {"Password", password},
                    {"ConfirmPassword", confirmPassword},
                    };

                var httpContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(model);
                    var response = await client.PostAsync(
                        Constants.EndpointAddress + "Account/Register", httpContent);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
```

thanks